# How to rotate base points of a scalene triangle to represent an isosceles triangle

Tags: trigonometry, rotations

Given the following graph:

[image]

Where **SP** is the start point and **EP** is the end point of a line - how would I rotate **p1** and **p2** on axis **SP** in such a way that they would represent an isosceles triangle e.g.

[image]

Comment: What is special about the second picture? For example, do you want your triangle to be isosceles?

Comment: @dtldarek Judging from the title of the question, I'd say 'yes'

Comment: @dtldarek yes, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the distance between say $p_1$ and $SP$, $d = |SP - p_1|$.  Suppose $v := EP - SP = (v_1, v_2)$.  Then  $n = (-v_2, v_1)$ is the direction you need to go in. Then your points are $SP \pm  \frac{d n}{|n|}$

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on `v := EP - SP = (v1, v2)`? i.e. where does v1/v2 come from (bit rusty with maths!).

Comment: Let $EP = (x_1, y_1)$ and $SP = (x_2, y_2)$.  Then what I meant is that $v = (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1)$.  So $n$ would then be $(y_1 - y_2, x_2 - x_1)$.

Comment: Thanks and the last formula could you explain the last equation i.e. `dn/|n|`? I understand that **p1/p2** will be the `SP` +- whatever the value of that equation is.

Comment: I suppose you need to know what $|v|$ means, $|v|$ is the length of a vector $v$ and you can calculate it in 2-dimensions by doing $|(v_1, v_2)| = \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2}$.

So, after you find $d = |SP - p_1|$, you then take the vector we just calculated $n$, first scale it by $d$, then scale it by $1 / |n|$

Comment: So in laymans terms - `P1 := SP - (d x n / √ n)`?